# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: node.js, express, path, ejs

I am getting the error : ENOENT: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\NodeLearning\Image-converter\output.jpg'`
this is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const gm = require("gm");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view-engine", "ejs");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.post("/", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    res.send("please upload a image!");
  }
  console.log(req.file.path);
  gm(req.file.path).write("output.jpg", function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.download("output.jpg");
  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on post 5000");
});
```

My EJS code is :

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Select Image:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image" id="image">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Convert Image</button>

</form>
```

The image is uploading properly but the issue is in downloading and converting the image I don't know where I made mistake but it's I think in the directory or path specified problem.
please have a look at my folder structure :
[image]

Comment: `res.download("output.jpg");` is looking for the file in the root of the application. You need to change `"output.jpg"` to the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happen usually in your system if you haven't updated the `path` variable for [GM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) to update the `path variable` you have to download the tool GM (GraphicsMagick) .exe for windows. for downloading the tool click here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/

after installing restart your system and good to go :)